# Remote manage Hyper-V

Tags: windows-server-2012, hyper-v, windows-10

Background:
At work we have these 4 physical servers running Windows Server 2012 Standard, running Hyper-V (Don't ask me why it's like this).
The connect just fine to each other so that you can manage all from one.

I want to control them from my machine so that I don't have to RDP into one of them to manage the virtual machines.
I know that it is possible to remotely manage Hyper-V, but when I try to add a remote server my system asks me if I want to enable delegation of user credentials, which I accept. This returns a "CredSSP authentication is currently disabled" error.

When I try executing `Enable-PSRemoting -force` I get an error telling me that one or more of the networks that I am or have previously connected to is set to "Public".
So after editing the registry and trying again, there is no difference.

I don't know how to enable this remote management, so if any of you have a solution or some hints they are very welcome.

**Edit:**
Added missing information about the task I'm trying to perform.

Answer (score 4):

> I know that this is possible, but when I try my system asks me if I want to enable delegation of user credentials, which I accept.

When you try what?

You shouldn't need to run anything through powershell

Download RSAT tools, you can install locally and then enable hyper-v manager though programs and features -> Turn windows feature on or off.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45520

Comment: Woops, forgot to write, that I'm trying to add a remote Hyper-V server. My question is updated :)

Comment: I believe your solution will work, but I'm not able to install RSAT due to GPO limits and I'm not going to try to find the right one, just for this. Also because we are going to redo the entire setup soon.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this link should help you to solve PowerShell remote management issue: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2504.enable-powershell-remoting-with-client-outside-of-server-s-domain-trusted-host-and-double-hop-issue.aspx

Similar SpiceWorks thread: 
https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2091878-i-can-t-connect-to-a-hyper-v-2016-server-to-remote-manage-it-from-windows-10

More links about issue:
https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/powershell/module/Microsoft.WsMan.Management/Enable-WSManCredSSP?view=powershell-5.1
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/taylorb/2012/03/23/hyper-v-remote-management-with-powershell/
https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28729522/Hyper-V-2012-R2-Core.html
https://thycotic.force.com/support/s/article/Configuring-CredSSP-for-use-with-WinRM-PowerShell